# My listbox doesn't update

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox to which I'm binding `HistoryItems` , where `HistoryItems` is a `ObservableCollection` of `History`.
 Here is the listbox declaration :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="RecentListBox" SelectionChanged="RecentListBox_SelectionChanged"   ItemsSource="{Binding HistoryItems,Converter={StaticResource HistoryValueConverter} }" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1_Wrap}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RecentViewModelTemplate}">
```

Here is the `History` class :

```
public class History : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public History() { }

        int _id;
        string _date;
        string _url;
        string _name;

        public History(int id, string date,string url,string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.date = date;
            this.url = url;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int id
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _id)
                {
                    _id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("id");
                }
            }
        }
        public string date
        {
            get
            {
                return _date;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_date))
                {
                    _date = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("string");
                }
            }
        }

        public string url
        {
            get
            {
                return _url;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_url))
                {
                    _url = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("url");
                }
            }
        }

        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_name))
                {
                    _name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("name");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
              //  App.viewModel.HistoryItems = (App.Current as App).dataHandler.retrieveHistory_DB();
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

When I start the app the list gets populated, but after I do some modifs in some pivot children, and go back to the main panorama view, I try to update the `HistoryItems` in  `OnNavigatedTo` :

```
 App.ViewModel.HistoryItems = (App.Current as App).dataHandler.retrieveHistory_DB();
```

but the listbox doesn't get updated (and the function returns the correct data). What could the problem be? `History` is `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the `HistoryItems` is a `ObservableCollection<History>` so there should be no problem.. What is causing the list to not update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are replacing `HistoryItems` when you refresh it doesn't matter that it's an `ObservableCollection`.

You can either clear the `HistoryItems` and then add the new items when you refresh. Or the `ViewModel` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the `HistoryItems` setter should raise the event.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the setter for ViewModel.HistoryItems so that instead of doing this

```
_historyItems = value;
```

it does this

```
if (_historyItems == null) 
  _historyItems = new ObservableCollection<HistoryItem>();
_historyItems.Clear();
foreach (var hi in value) 
  _historyItems.Add(hi);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `NotifyPropertyChanged` for `App.ViewModel` in the Setter of `HistoryItems`

Comment: Not so. Binding is directly supported by ObservableCollection<T>, that's why it's labelled as being observable.